# Navbar Extended Too Far on Mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm new to all this and I have been having issues with the mobile side view for a website I'm currently working on. The main issue seems to be my navbar width is extended too far on mobile devices and I think that's also causing other viewing issues with the site. Here the site - http://georgiapestcontrolcompany.com/

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#landingkit-navbar" data-offset="74">
    <div id="preloader">
        <div id="preloader-inner"></div>
    </div><!--/preloader-->

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white navbar-sticky">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#landingkit-navbar" aria-controls="landingkit-navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="landingkit-navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-scroll href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="#features">Pest Control</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="#termite">Termite Control</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="#fungus">Fungus Control</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="#lawn">Lawn Spraying</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="#faqs">Other Services</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto navbar-right">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="#">Serving South GA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" data-scroll href="#" style="font-weight: 900">229-924-7774</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your site is not `responsive`.

`owl-carousel` `width` is more than `width: 224520px;`. That is causing your `header`
**`Navbar Extended Too Far on Mobile`** .

Try to reduce `owl-carousel` `width` on mobile deice.

**OR**

Give `max-width: 100%;` of `owl-carousel`'s `parent(.row)`.

**It will fix your problem.**

Comment: You are fast +1

Comment: @ЙорданРамчев ,  :) .